# why sink watermark is higher watermark of two stream in flink

Tags: apache-flink

How should I understand this question

sink use higher of two watermark, make output data more wait.
I often find that in the flink webui, the recive records number of the source and the send records number of the sink are never displayed, for what reason.

[image]

my code:

```
    val UserOrderTableSql =
      """
        |create table user_order (
        | order_id string
        | ,d1 BIGINT
        | ,d2 AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(d1, 3)
        | ,WATERMARK FOR d2 AS d2
        |)WITH(
        |    'connector' = 'kafka',
        |      'topic' = 'u6',
        |      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
        |      'properties.group.id' = 'g123456',
        |      'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
        |      'format' = 'json'
        |)
        |""".stripMargin
    tEnv.executeSql(UserOrderTableSql)
//      tEnv.executeSql("select * from user_order").print()


    // {"order_id":"100","paymoney":123,"time1":1688261952148}
    val paymentFlow =
      """
        |create table user_pay (
        | order_id string,
        | paymoney bigint,
        | time1 BIGINT,
        | time2 AS TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(time1, 3),
        | WATERMARK FOR time2 AS time2,
        | PRIMARY KEY(order_id) NOT ENFORCED
        |)WITH(
        |    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
        |      'topic' = 'dim4',
        |      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
        |      'properties.group.id' = 'g1',
        |      'key.format' = 'raw',
        |      'value.format' = 'json'
        |)
        |""".stripMargin
    tEnv.executeSql(paymentFlow)


    tEnv.executeSql(
      """
        |select
        |   l.order_id,
        |   l.d1,
        |   r.paymoney,
        |   r.time1,
        |   l.d2
        |from user_order as l left join user_pay FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF l.d2 AS r
        |on l.order_id = r.order_id
        |""".stripMargin)
      .print()
```

Comment: The metrics displaying records sent and received only count records sent within Flink, using Flink's internal network. Data read from and written to external systems (sources and sinks) is not included in these metrics.